# My new Intel X25-M G2 and the alignment thingy

Tags: linux, ssd, alignment, gpt, grub2

I just bought a new SSD for my laptop, which is going to be a server running ArchLinux with grub2, GPT and btrfs.

My layout should look like this:

```
(grub-partition?)
/boot  ext2   75MB
/      btrfs  15GB
/home  btrfs  remaining
```

What do I need to do to create these partitions in a correctly aligned fashion using parted?

Do I need to consider alignment when formatting each partition with the desired file system?

Comment: Duh, theres an alignment thingy to think about with the X25MG2? And I just installed them without thinking...

Comment: Yeah, you gotta check this post http://ldn.linuxfoundation.org/blog-entry/aligning-filesystems-ssd%E2%80%99s-erase-block-size

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a clear explanation a little tool to verify the resulting values.

- [Simple explanation howto align your partitions correctly using parted and a GPT](http://www.ocztechnologyforum.com/forum/showthread.php?54379-Linux-Tips-tweaks-and-alignment&p=472998&viewfull=1#post472998)
- A little web app to verify your results: www.techpowerup.com/articles/other/157

Good Luck!

Answer (score -1):

Since the Intel X25M-G2 supports the TRIM-command and uses "garbage collection" an alignment to erase-blocks should not be overly important anymore if the Linux-kernel you are using supports TRIM as well.

For example the kernel used in Ubuntu 10.10 will support TRIM.

Comment: Umm...I don't think that's correct.  You'd still like everything to be aligned whether you have TRIM or not, in fact TRIM is almost completely unrelated to alignment - the only relationship I can see is that if you're not aligned, as time goes by you'll have more of a mess (maybe only slightly more, but more) for TRIM to clean up.

Comment: Forgot to add a link to the Paragon page that has a pretty good graphical explanation of what's up with alignment:  http://www.paragon-software.com/business/partition-alignment/index.html  I think their claims of a 300% boost are probably a little unrealistic, but you can see the potential inefficiency - basically if you're not aligned, you will (sometimes) have to write more blocks to save the same amount of data.